# What Does a -0 in the Number argument for DATEADD Mean?

Tags: sql-server, dateadd

I am practicing reading and understanding more advanced queries and I ran into this:

```
,DATENAME(Month, dateadd(day,-0, event_last_date)) + ' ' +
       DATENAME(day, dateadd(day,-0, event_last_date))   + ', ' +                        
       DATENAME(year, dateadd(day,-0, event_last_date))                                 AS 'earliest_mail_date'
```

I do not understand what the purpose of the -0 is. If you are not adding anything, why even use the DATEADD function?

Comment: There is no purpose, maybe someone was paid by number of lines code...

Comment: Are you sure that this code has been made by a human coder and is not the result of some kind of automated framework ?. They tend to be overly complex, like this one.